# Как развернуть django приложение на heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, развертывание

Хочу развернуть простейшее API на Heroku

Пользуюсь **Windows** и запускаю локальный сервер с помощью `python manage.py runserver`, это же прописал в `Procfile`

В Heroku успешно зарегистрировался по команде `heroku login` и `heroku create` прошли успешно.

После чего с предварительно созданным `requrements.txt` выполняю `git push heroku master` и мне выводится ошибка 
`App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz`

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109465/app-not-compatible-with-buildpack-heroku) пишут, что проблема может быть из-за корневой папки, но структура моего проекта выглядит так:

[image]

И команды исполняются из этой же папки `(web_env) C:\web_adgame\adgame.github.io>git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

Все незатронутые системой контроля версий, а тут это git, файлы не будут видны при команде `git push heroku master`

1. `git add [требуемые файлы]`
2. `git commit -m "сообщение коммита"`
3. `git push heroku master`

Теперь всё должно пройти успешно.